# kdevelop 3.5: configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, g++, automake, kdevelop

I try to compile an application with kdevelop 3.5.4 on Ubuntu 10.04, but it fails with the following errors:

```
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/nts/wktools4':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
*** Exited with status: 77 ***
```

config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.65.  Invocation command line was

  $ /home/nts/wktools4/configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = wktools-l-64
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.32-21-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:09:38 UTC 2010

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2382: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2450: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2461: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2511: result: yes
configure:2652: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2691: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2704: checking for gawk
configure:2720: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2731: result: gawk
configure:2742: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2764: result: yes
configure:2909: checking for g++
configure:2925: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:2936: result: g++
configure:2963: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:2972: g++ --version >&5
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2983: $? = 0
configure:2972: g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i486 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 
configure:2983: $? = 0
configure:2972: g++ -V >&5
g++: '-V' option must have argument
configure:2983: $? = 1
configure:2972: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: unrecognized option '-qversion'
g++: no input files
configure:2983: $? = 1
configure:3003: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:3025: g++ -funsigned-char -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-static-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -pthread  -L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwxcode_gtk2_propgrid-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_xml-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_net-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base-2.8.a -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lXinerama -lSM -lpng -lexpat -lwxtiff-2.8 -lwxjpeg-2.8 -lz -ldl –lm conftest.cpp  >&5
g++: –lm: No such file or directory
configure:3029: $? = 1
configure:3067: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "wktools4"
| #define VERSION "0.1"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3072: error: in `/home/nts/wktools4':
configure:3076: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value='-funsigned-char -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-static-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -pthread'
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwxcode_gtk2_propgrid-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_xml-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_net-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base-2.8.a -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lXinerama -lSM -lpng -lexpat -lwxtiff-2.8 -lwxjpeg-2.8 -lz -ldl –lm'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/nts/wktools4/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/nts/wktools4/missing --run tar'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/nts/wktools4/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/nts/wktools4/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/nts/wktools4/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='gawk'
CC=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++'
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS='-funsigned-char -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-static-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -pthread'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwxcode_gtk2_propgrid-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_xml-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_net-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base-2.8.a -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lXinerama -lSM -lpng -lexpat -lwxtiff-2.8 -lwxjpeg-2.8 -lz -ldl –lm'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/nts/wktools4/missing --run makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='wktools4'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
VERSION='0.1'
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/nts/wktools4/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
lt_ECHO='echo'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "wktools4"
#define VERSION "0.1"

configure: exit 77
```

I have no idea what's wrong. Could it be a version mismatch of the used tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `LDFLAGS` environment variable ends with `–lm` instead of `-lm` (i.e. you used a unicode dash instead of the ASCII dash), so instead of finding the math library, your compiler tries to load a file named `–lm` and complains with `g++: –lm: No such file or directory`.

Comment: adl, how do you see this? Thank you very much for your help!  
/mspoerr